# Is it possible add JSON value as property value?

Tags: javascript, rdf, skos

I'm trying to add a property value that represent a JSON value and it shouldn't be escaped, but I can't find how properly set the CDATASection. Anyone could help me?

```
const predicate = rdflib.namedNode(property.uri, this._config));
const object = rdflib.lit(property.value, property.language, namespaces.rdf('JSON'));
    this._store.add(this._rdflib_node, predicate, object, this._why);
```